# iOS get error Dependency for P1: Debug:SwiftDriver Compilation Requirements app normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler is not absolute

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, facebook, xcode14

we decided to update macOS and XCode to lunching our react-native app on new version softwares although  it had some weird errors, ran and built success. we ignored them at that time but when we wanted to get an archive those error presented and made archiving failed.

there tow type of error

1. some of theme belong to TensorFlowLiteSwift like below(23 errors like these error ):

> Dependency for P1:target-app-      69a90293829c4577a609157fb85f5e0d7ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:SwiftDriver Compilation Requirements app normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler is not absolute (Pods/TensorFlowLiteC/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/Modules/module.modulemap).

2.some of theme refer to heaers in pods(6 errors like these):

> 69a90293829c4577a609157fb85f5e0d7ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:SwiftDriver Compilation Requirements app normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler is not absolute (Pods/Headers/Public/FBLPromises/PromisesObjC.modulemap).

we faced with this error with :

| softeare | version |
| --- | --- |
| XCode | 14.1 |
| react-native | 69.3 |
| TensorFlowLiteSwift | 2.3.0 |
| TensorFlowLiteSwift | 2.3.0 |
| cocoapods | 11.12.1 |
| PromisesObjC | 1.2.12 |
| macOs | 13.4 |
| ruby | 2.63 (tested 2.7.4) |

on apple macmini intel

**we try to solve it by solutions below:
**

1. add [system] after our framework module in modulemap files (it removes TensorFlowLiteSwift errors pot 6 of them that appear because promisses still exist )
2. removing ${PROJECT_DIR} from User Header Search Path in build setting but it made other errors so it doesn't work

we stuck in it

please help us